# Android ImageView disappears under Buttons in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my game, I have got a RelativeLayout as my contentView.

It has got 5 views, 3 of them are important here:

1. A button (Has the game field as a background image)
2. An image view (The player)
3. A button (Moving objects in the game as a background image)

The background image of the 2nd button is mostly transparent.

I added all 3 views in this order to my RelativeLayout, but it appears that the image view is below the buttons, so you cannot see the player.

Why is that?

Even though this is a really simple, I could not find any answer to it.

Using a FrameLayout instead of a RelativeLayout didn't work out.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried layout below?? and also post the xml file here..

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code....

Comment: @BömachtBlau Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the default style of the `Button`s.

So I endet up using `TextView` (a `Button` without a style) and everything worked fine.